# Draw line with increasing lineWidth on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-graphics

I'm drawing a line on iOS by stroking a path onto a CALayer. How can I stroke this line with an increasing lineWidth (stroke width), so that the left end of the line is thinner than the right end? (It really has to be a line, not a shape or closed path, since I'm going to be using the strokeEnd property.)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a draw function. It's pretty annoying to get used to at first, but it does its job. If you need anymore help just leave comment

```
-(void)draw{
     float lineHeight = 5;//change this as you see fit, like set it equal to an incrementing/decrementing variable of your choice...
     glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
     glLineWidth(lineHeight); // change this as you see fit
     glColor4ub(255,255,255,255); // change these as you see fit :)
     ccDrawLine(ccp(10,310), ccp(30,310));  // these numbers are probably off, you'll   have to mess with these to get it in the right position :)
        [super draw];
        }
```

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this has something to do with cocos2D? I'm using a QuartzCore CALayer/CAShapeLayer, not CCLayer..

Comment: Oh crap sorry, you may need cocos2d for this... sorry I thought it was part of xcode.

Comment: Is there another possible solution, apart from using cocos2D?

Comment: Hrm... you could have the width set to a variable that changes with an NSTimer.